# Why Hund's first rule neglect one of the spin triplet states?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, exchange-interaction

For two electrons, the spin triplet states allow their spacial wavefunction to be antisymmetric with respect to the exchange of particles, and can minimize the coulomb repulsion energy because larger spcial seperation ( < x1-x2> ).Many textbook using the statement above to explaine the Hund's first rule. However, Hund's rule tells that the ground state is either spins up or both spins down. There is one of triplet 1/√2|↑↓>+|↓↑> being neglected, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Hund's (1st) rule is based on the fact that if we fill the atomic orbitals with electrons, we can minimize the electron repulsion interaction energy by first maximizing |S| by putting electrons in different orbitals (sometimes called the "bus seat" rule). By putting them in different orbitals, they occupy different regions of space on average and thus reduce their repulsion. (The real situation is actually more complicated and involves the fact that orbitals with only one electron are not screened as well).

If we are considering putting two electrons in the same energy level, then the spin triplet is strictly forbidden because it is forbidden by Pauli exclusion: the electrons cannot be in the same energy level and also have the same spin state.